# Emulate setTimeout with setInterval not working for nested

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I write extension for Chrome. And I need run delayed tasks when background page inactive. Cause setTimeout not working in background tabs, I try emulate setTimeout with setInterval, like code below (located in content script):

```
window.timings = [];

function set_timeout(func, time){
  var now = new Date() / 1;
  window.timings.push({
    func: func,
    time: time + now
  });
}

function tick(){
  var now = new Date() / 1;
  window.timings = window.timings.filter(function(delay_obj){
    if (now > delay_obj.time){
      delay_obj.func.call();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  setInterval(tick, 1000);
  // some code
});
```

And it don't work when set_interval call in delay function:

```
set_timeout(function(){
  console.log('func1');
}, 2000);

set_timeout(function(){
  console.log('func2');

  set_timeout(function(){
    console.log('func3');
  }, 3000);

}, 3000);
```

Output:

```
func1
func2
```

Why `func3` not displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently using an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) declared with `"persistent": false` in manifest.json, it is unloaded after 15 seconds of inactivity. The linked documentation says to use [chrome.alarms API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms).

- For a delay less than 15 seconds since the last `chrome` event:

  Use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.
- For a delay of 15-60 seconds since the last `chrome` event:

  Don't use the event page, switch to `"persistent": true` in manifest.json.
- For a delay of 60 seconds or more:

  manifest.json:

  ```
    "permissions": ["alarms"],
  ```

  background script:

  ```
    chrome.alarms.create("MyInterval1", {when: Date.now() + 1 * 60e3});

    chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
        if (alarm.name == "MyInterval1") {
            console.log("Yay!");
            chrome.alarms.create("MyInterval1", {when: Date.now() + 1 * 60e3});
        }
    });
  ```

  Also note:

  > Other asynchronous HTML5 APIs like notifications and geolocation will not complete if the event page shuts down. Instead, use equivalent extension APIs, like notifications.

  > If your extension uses, `extension.getBackgroundPage`, switch to `runtime.getBackgroundPage` instead. The newer method is asynchronous so that it can start the event page if necessary before returning it.

Note that in a published extension the interval between the next alarm and the last fired alarm is at least 1 minute even if you specify a smaller value like 15 seconds (15*1000).

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/#method-create

> In order to reduce the load on the user's machine, Chrome limits
> alarms to at most once every 1 minute but may delay them an arbitrary
> amount more. That is, setting `delayInMinutes` or `periodInMinutes` to
> less than 1 will not be honored and will cause a warning. `when` can
> be set to less than 1 minute after `"now"` without warning but won't
> actually cause the alarm to fire for at least 1 minute.
>
> To help you debug your app or extension, when you've loaded it
> unpacked, there's no limit to how often the alarm can fire.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But ended up, I decide use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` in background.js calling from setInterval function and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` in content script