# Optimize and improve timed function in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, opera

I'm working on an extension for Chrome Browser and Opera browser.
I have a part of the code in the background.js file that I think is not optimized and use too much resource. Currently with only the browser opened and the extension installed the browser use 0.5/1 percent of CPU.

My code is something like this:

```
    setInterval(function()
{
    $.getJSON( "link of json", function( data ) {

    if(data.length > 10)
    {
        showNotification(str);
    }

    });
}, 30000)
```

Every 30 seconds the extension do a request for a json file, and after check the if. The extension use that CPU without entering in the if.

There is a way to optimize or do in a better way this type of code?

Comment: Use an event page: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33386546)

Comment: I should create an Event.js that get called from the background.js every 30 seconds using the alarms?

Comment: If I understood correctly event page after 5 seconds become "unloaded" so it should improve resource management, but while it is "unloaded" it continue to do the timed function and in case the if is true it show the notifications?

Comment: Indeed. The only background page you will have will be an event page and it'll unload automatically and the local variables will be undefined on next run so use chrome.storage.local or localStorage.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help.

Comment: Did it solve the issue? I'll post it as answer then.

Comment: The eventPage never unload, but however Cpu and Memory are better.
Cpu is always 0% and when it do the request go to 0.1%